# Infinite Loop Arm Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, microcontroller

I am unsure if this loop would happen infinitely or stop after 2^32 times and continue running.

```
mov r5, #10
label_a:
    adds r5, #1
    bne label_a
```

Comment: it depends on what r4 is set to before you start, yes if it is zero then it will loop until it rolls around to zero again.

Comment: how would it go indefinitely, how would it not hit zero at some point?

Comment: @old_timer Sorry that was meant to be r5 not r4 so I am guessing it would go to 2^32 - 10?

Comment: yes basically, it will count to 0xFFFFFFFF then when the next add happens the result is zero and bne does not branch (as documented, the zero flag is set when the result is zero and bne branches if Z is not set)

Comment: Yeah so basically stack pointer would start at 0xFFFFFFFF and then keep incrementing to get to 0x00000000 but since r5 is initialized to 10, the stack would stop at 2^32 - 10?

Comment: The stack is not used at all in this code.  Only general purpose register r5 and the program counter (pc) change.  The stack pointer is unmodified.  This is a simple loop not a recursive function call.  @old_timer why not copy your comment to an answer and claim the points?

Comment: Somehow my previous comment got deleted.  This is something you can try yourself.  With a 1GHz CPU and a loop taking maybe 2 clock cycles, 2^32 iterations will take about 12 seconds or so to be sure it's not infinite.  Or better, single step with a debugger to see what happens with the register close to wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
mov r5, #10
label_a:
    adds r5, #1
    bne label_a
```

as written.  outside the loop r5 is loaded with the value 10 decimal.  The register is 32 bits.  adds r5,#1 adds one to r5 and the s indicates save the flags one of which is the zero flag.

```
if ConditionPassed(cond) then
  Rd = Rn + shifter_operand
  if S == 1 and Rd == R15 then
    CPSR = SPSR
  else if S == 1 then
    N Flag = Rd[31]
    Z Flag = if Rd == 0 then 1 else 0
    C Flag = CarryFrom(Rn + shifter_operand)
    V Flag = OverflowFrom(Rn + shifter_operand)
```

Then the NE condition on B(ranch) means

```
0001 NE Not equal Z clear
```

so r5 after the add will go 11,12,13,14....0xFFFFFFFE, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000
and that 0x00000000 will set the zero flag and the bne will not meet its condition and will not branch, end of loop.

Whether that is 2^32-10 or 2^32-10-1 times through the loop, I always have to write down on paper and count, I have some mental block there in memorizing that.  But this can be an exercise for the reader.

Comment: no I dont count to four billion on paper...0xFA, 0xFB, 0xFC, 0xFD, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0x00.  So yes 2^32-10 times through the loop.